A question on a quantitative form of Farkas' lemma
Suppose A is an $m \times n$ matrix whose entries are non-negative integers and $\mathbf{b}$ is a vector with rational entries. A version of Farkas lemma implies that if the equation $$A\mathbf{x}=\mathbf{b}$$ has no non-negative integer solution (that is, a solution $\mathbf{x}$ where all entries of $x$ are non-negative integers), then there exists an integer vector $\mathbf{y} \in \mathbb{Z}^m$ such that   $A^T \mathbf{y} \ge 0$ and $\mathbf{b}^T \mathbf{y}<0$. I think it is reasonable that the size of $\mathbf{y}$ can be bounded by the size of entries of A. However, I have not been able to find it anywhere.
Question: Is there a version of this theorem which provides such a bound, and if so, I would be thankful for a pointer to a reference.

Yes, thanks for noticing it. It is fixed now.

If you are looking for polynomial bounds (polynomial in the entries of $A$ and of the scaled-into-the-integers form of $\mathbf b$), then this follows from Theorem 10.1 in Alexander Schrijver, Theory of linear and integer programming, Wiley 1999.

Thanks! In the situation I need to handle, the entries are 0-1, but the size of the matrix can be large, so Theorem 10.1 (which is based on Corollary 3.2b) gives a poor bound. Do you happen to know if there is a chance for something better in general?
